# How can I have common number (i.e., share a counter) between a tcolorbox theorem environment and a standard theorem environment?

Tags: numbering, tcolorbox, theorems, counters, amsthm

I have a document where I want to have theorems formatted using the tcolorbox package, and propositions formatted using the default formatting from the amsthm package.

However, I'd also like to have my theorems and propositions have a shared counter and use a consistent numbering scheme (e.g., if in section 2 I have a theorem and then a proposition, the theorem should be labeled as Theorem 2.1, and the proposition should be labeled as Proposition 2.2).

Normally, I would define the theorem environment and then write

```
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
```

but doing this produces an error message: "LaTeX Error: No counter 'theorem' defined."

Since the above does not work, how should I setup my theorem and proposition to make sure they have shared numbering?

An small example for the packages and environments I'm working with is included below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem
  [number within=section, Crefname={Theorem}{Theorems}]% init options
  {theorem}% name
  {Theorem}% title
  {colframe=gray!40!black}% options
  {theorem}% prefix
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
%% Using below command produces "LaTeX Error: No counter 'theorem' defined."
% \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}

\begin{theorem}{Example Theorem}{referencing}
A major result. 
\end{theorem}

\begin{proposition}
    A minor result.
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a peak in your `.aux` file and find out that the counter used by tcolorbox for your theorem is called `tcb@cnt@theorem`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem
  [number within=section, Crefname={Theorem}{Theorems}]% init options
  {theorem}% name
  {Theorem}% title
  {colframe=gray!40!black}% options
  {theorem}% prefix
\makeatletter
\newtheorem{proposition}[tcb@cnt@theorem]{Proposition}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}

\begin{theorem}{Example Theorem}{referencing}
A major result. 
\end{theorem}

\begin{proposition}
    A minor result.
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

[image]